# Is Facebook App Review required for public_profile

Tags: facebook

Yesterday for one of my facebook applications I received an alert message in the developers console that states:

> App Review required by August 1, 2018 to retain access to Facebook Platform APIs ... if your ap is not submitted you will loose access to these permissions: user_link, user_gender, user_age_range, user_friends

My application only uses the `public_profile` permission, which does not require review according to their [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/what-is-login-review).

At the same time I am not able to submit my application for review from the developers console because it requires login permissions to be selected and `public_profile` is not listed there.

Should I be worried that I can't submit my App for review or am I misunderstanding the 'App review form'?

Answer (score 1):

`public_profile` is deprecated in v3.0 of the Graph API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version3.0

It is just a warning though, if you don´t use those permissions then you should be fine for now. Take a look at the changelog about `public_profile` replacements though.

Comment: I don't think it's just a warning, again from their documentation:
'If your app is not approved or you don't submit for review, people will not be able to use Facebook Login in your app'. At the same time I am using facebook login through Firebase, so I guess they should be the one worrying about public_profile being deprecated.

Comment: i got this even for apps without any facebook login, so it can only be a warning.